# how to run html code when i click on a button

Tags: html, web, button, click, alert

I have to make a website for school and I have chosen to make a fake webshop.
I want to make a button run code but i cant find out how to do it.

The button's code:

```
<button style="
text-decoration: none;
font-size: x-large;
color: white;
background-color: blue;
position: absolute;
top: 80%;
left: 10%;
width: 20%;
height: 10%;
right: 70%;
bottom: 10%;
">
buy
</button>
```

The code that need to be run:

```
alert("out of stock")
```

Answer (score 1):

here's the code that'll help you:

```js
function outofstock() {
  alert("Out of Stock!");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="outofstock()"style="
text-decoration: none;
font-size: x-large;
color: white;
background-color: blue;
position: absolute;
top: 80%;
left: 10%;
width: 20%;
height: 10%;
right: 70%;
bottom: 10%;
">
buy
</button>
```

You can run the code snippet and check it, hope this helps! (:

Let me know if there's any other Html/CSS-related help you need...

Answer (score -1):

You can use the javascript [onclick Event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) for this.

BTW: You can easily install a fake shop by using wordpress / woocommerce!

Answer (score -1):

i guess you can do

`onclick="myFunction()"` in your button,

and add near the end :

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    alert("I am an alert box!");
}
</script>
```

but i recommend to use 3 different files, a css a Javascript and an HTML

Answer (score -1):

Try this out:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>

<script>
function myFunction(){
alert("Out of Stock");
};
</script>
```